# How to position 6 bootstrap containers in a responsive manner?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 6 containers that are positioned like so:

```
   *
 *   *
 * * *
```

Where each `*` represents the positioning of the container. How would you make this layout responsive so that they eventually become one under each other like so:

```
*
*
*
*
*
*
```

Comment: Use bootstrap's grid system

Comment: I thought you cannot put containers inside containers?

Comment: If you refer to the wrapping div you give the class container, you actually need only one for the whole document. The layout you want can be acomplished with the grid system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.row > .col-sm-4 {
  background: #eee;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  outline: 1px solid #ddd
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 offset-sm-4">1. Lorem ipsum...</div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">2. Lorem ipsum...</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 offset-sm-4">3. Lorem ipsum...</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">4. Lorem ipsum...</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">5. Lorem ipsum...</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">6. Lorem ipsum...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```